# Why can't find ffmpeg || ffprobe error in Docker build even locally it's working fine

Tags: node.js, docker, ffmpeg, node-modules, dock

I got this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glGAQ.png
from this code https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8dHd.png

I need to compress the video size to reduce the uploading time to server and using ffmpeg but this error in docker build even locally it's working fine. Now i need to remove this error . On the other hand everything woring fine, modules also installed.